# Building a eloquent query belongsTo for octobercms

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I'm working on a report widget for OctoberCMS and need to build in some conditional statements for my query.

I have a table (user_access_log) that contains records for the user id, ip address, and time stamps.

My access log model is this:

```
/**
 * @var array
 */
 public $belongsTo = [
    'user' => ['Models\User']
 ];
```

My user model is such:

```
/**
 * @var array Relations
 */
public $belongsToMany = [
    'groups' => ['Models\UserGroup', 'table' => 'users_groups']
];
```

UPDATE:
Now I have extended the user model like so:

```
UserModel::extend(function($model)
{
    $model->hasMany['logs'] = [
        'Models\AccessLog',
        'key' => 'user_id',
    ];
});
```

and updated the query for my widget to:

```
$query = UserGroup::whereHas('user',function($query) {
    $query->whereHas('logs',function($query) {
        // Just some query to get a resultset back so count() > 1
        $query->whereNotNull('created_at');
    });
 });

$userLog = $query->where('name', 'Users')->get();
```

However, I am still not returning any results. In fact, its as if the query is not even running. Nothing is displayed in my Debugbar. I tried to pass the array to my view and it now says I have an undefined variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do the query before call `all()` because at these point you will got an Eloquent Collection and no the Query Builder

```
$log = AccessLog::whereHas('user', function($q){
     $q->whereHas('groups', function($subquery){
      $subquery->where('name', '=', 'staff');
     }
})->get()->groupBy('user_id');
```

This could be works :D

Comment: I see where you're going but this still didn't do it for me unfortunately. And I needed to add a ';' to the end of the subquery function.

Answer (score 0):

A recap of what you have:

An accesslog entry that belongs to ONE user.
An User that belongs to Many groups.
A group that belongs to Many users.

What you want, is to see which groups have come from all access logs.

You need to implement a hasMany relationship in your user.

```
$hasMany = [
      'logs' => [
         'Models\AccessLog', 
         'key'=> 'user_id'
       ],
];
```

Then you can build a query like:

```
$query = UserGroup::whereHas('user',function($query) {
   $query->whereHas('logs',function($query) {
       // Just some query to get a resultset back so count() > 1
       $query->whereNotNull('created_at');
   });
});
$staff = $query->where('name','staff')->get();
```

Comment: I implemented your suggestion and am still not returning anything. See my update when you have time.

Comment: if you do `$userLog = $query->where('name', 'Users')->toSql();` what kind of query do you get? and does the UserGroup also contain a column called 'name' and does it contain a value 'Users' ?

Comment: Tried that and its not returning anything; still getting undefined variable from the widget partial. Also, the user_groups table does contain a name column and has a value with Users. I also looked at the users_groups table, which only has user_id and user_group_id listed. I tried manipulating the $userlog line to where('user_group_id','2') and still nothing. I feel like this is more difficult than it should be which tells me im not doing something right.